# Set Xorg and gnome-shell to run on a single graphics card

Tags: nvidia, xorg, gnome-shell, 20.10, dual-graphics

I have two Nvidia graphics cards in my PC. I would like to have gnome-shell and Xorg to run only one of them. In this case on GPU 0 only. How can I configure that? Here is the output of nvidia-smi.[image]

I have a GTX970 and RTX 3090. I use the RTX 3090 for CUDA only so I would like to free up the memory that is used by gnome-shell and X11 on it. By default, Ubuntu launches on both cards. Is there a way to set bind gnome-shell and X11 to one only?

Comment: So which card is your display plugged in to?

Comment: Why do you only use the RTX 3090 for only CUDA? It is a _very_ high end card, so it very likely can do display output and your CUDA task, even if the CUDA task is very GPU intensive, like rendering. I suggest just using the RTX 3090 for display output and CUDA unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I plug the display into the GTX970. Awhile back I was able to have gnome and x11 on just one card. This is mainly out of curiousity but when launching application such it uses up the memory on RTX3090 card which I rather just dedicate to CUDA applications. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an open [GNOME Bug Report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6146) on the topic.